# What's the name of this kind of workers and of this equipment?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

This goes back early 1900s I imagine. In this NYTimes video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tly8abRH4ws (2'05'') there are five men on a railroad equipment. I tried looking for pictures and on americanrails.com, but found no clue to get to the name of that kind of workers and to the thing they are giving motion to.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: [***Gandy dancer** is a slang term used for early railroad workers who laid and maintained railroad tracks in the years before the work was done by machines. The British equivalents of the term **gandy dancer** are "**navvy**" (from "navigator"), originally builders of canals or "inland navigations", for builders of railway lines, and "**platelayer**" for workers employed to inspect and maintain the track.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandy_dancer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vehicle is a **handcar** or pumpcar.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handcar

Answer (score 3):

**Navvys** or **Navigational Engineers**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navvy

Comment: The conventional plural spelling would be _navvies_ (not navvys).

Comment: As FumbleFingers states, "gandy dancer" is the US term for the people.  I've never heard "navvy".

Comment: ^vote with an note: You could add a parallel reference to *gandy dancer*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandy_dancer

Comment: Recommended video accompaniment to this answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fh0F41AvO_Q

Comment: @Hotlicks Navvy was the general term used in and around Britain, especially for Irish engineers. As a large amount of Irish Navvies went to the US to work on these projects, I used Navvy.